# From SVN to Git on Windows and then GitHub

Tags: windows, git, svn

I am using windows and contribute to a folder https://svn.aaaaa.bbb/c which is hosted on a unix server. We are using svn to manage the versions, and on my computer I use tortoise SVN. I need to first create a git folder which includes all the information (and history of versions, in case we need to revert back) from the svn repo, and then push this to a shared folder on Github.

As the first step, I created a new folder, and then used the following command on Git Bash:

```
    git svn clone https://svn.aaaaa.bbb/c -T trunk -b branches -t tags
```

I am following this [tutorial](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client). The folder c is created, and inside it I see .git folder, but none of the shared files and folder have been transferred.

Could you let me know how to fix this?

The second question is what is the best way to push this to github to preserve all the history? Will

```
 git push -u origin master
```

be enough?

Once the GitHub version is up and running, we will not work with the SVN shared folder.

Comment: `git svn clone` should provide output of what is going on (revisions it is going thru, branch it is currently working on). Is there any output like that? Then, you should be able to see what it is creating as it is working if on a separate terminal you run `git branch -a`

Comment: And then when you have your branches in git, just add a new _remote_ to that git repo that points to the github repo and start pushing branches. Check `git help remote`

Comment: @eftshift0 while the command above (git svn clone ...) was running, I did not see any outputs on Gitbash window. Also when I run git branch -a nothing is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you clone and have to work later with single folder in SVN (not the whole tree), it will be more reasonable to use just `git svn clone https://svn.aaaaa.bbb/c` (see first example from [Basic Samples](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_basic_examples) in Gin SVN doc)
2. I'm not sure, but using relative paths with non-root URL of source may be The Bad Idea: repo-URL *have to be* minimized, but starting point of relative URL *may be* original, thus - all subtrees will not be found. Try to use full URLs for branches and tags, if you need this data (or read p.1)
3. Pure clone doesn't create|update working tree after even successful clone AFAICR, you have to do it by hand